# upowerd hogging CPU while iPhone is connected

Tags: 16.04, process, ubuntu-mate

It appears that `upowerd` is hogging my cpu time, I killed the process, but it has returned, and is climbing in resource consumption. Do I need upower? can I disable it?

I am using ubuntu Mate 16.04.

heres a screen-shot from the `top` command
[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have an iPhone plugged into your computer ? If so, you may need to select "Trust this computer" on the phone (or disconnect it), which may fix it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/861642

Comment: ... why yes, I do, and hey, yeah its fixed!

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't have an iPhone plugged in (I don't even have an iPhone!) or any other external device. Only a MicroSD card but upowerd hogs my CPU even with no MicroSD inserted so there must be some other explanation for it.

Comment: If the question has been answered please mark the answer so that others do not then see it as unanswered

Comment: @JonasCz Wow, this has been a good day for finding amazingly perfect answers on the first attempt

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From @JonasCz, whose comment was:

> Do you happen to have an iPhone plugged into your computer ? If so,
>   you may need to select "Trust this computer" on the phone (or
>   disconnect it), which may fix it:
>   bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/861642

Unplugging the Iphone solved the issue, or was an acceptable answer for me.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too!  I "trusted" the computer from my iPhone and that fixed it.

Comment: Wow, spot on - ripped out the cable: Gone. Psyhco. Didn't help to kill it either, it just came back. (But @JonasCz should have the credit!)

Comment: Well that was easy. Crazy stuff...

Comment: Why iPhone8 can not remember the `trust` option each time plugged to Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2):

This just happened when I resumed the computer this morning. Going into suspend last night I had Power Panel left open. This morning Power Panel was all greyed out and the hard disk light was flashing like a disco light show.

I used these commands:

```
$ ps -aux | grep upowerd | grep -v grep
root      2013  0.5  0.0 349976  7372 ?        Rsl  Aug11  11:12 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd

$ sudo killall -9 upowerd
```

Of course now `upowerd` isn't running at all but that's OK it'll come back with the next reboot. I don't use it much anyway just to check when wireless mouse or keyboard batteries are low.

Comment: You can just `pgrep -a upowerd` to avoid the `grep -v`

Comment: @PabloBianchi Thanks for that! Almost as cool as when I learned about `pkill -f <NAME>` once instead of using `kill <PID>` a whole bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

I had a 3DConnexion device (3D Spacemouse) connected via USB and unplugging it solved my problem CPU hogging problem.